# How to show that the gradient descent for unconstrained optimization can be represented as the argmin of a quadratic?

Tags: optimization, proof-explanation, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent

In the FISTA paper, [it writes](https://people.rennes.inria.fr/Cedric.Herzet/Cedric.Herzet/Sparse_Seminar/Entrees/2012/11/12_A_Fast_Iterative_Shrinkage-Thresholding_Algorithmfor_Linear_Inverse_Problems_(A._Beck,_M._Teboulle)_files/Breck_2009.pdf):

[image]

I have literally been stuck on this line for days. I don't have access to the text and I couldn't find any information online about this equivalence. Can someone please provide some guidance as to why these two expressions are equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $$g(x) = f(x_{k-1}) + \langle x - x_{k-1}, \nabla f(x_{k-1})\rangle + \tfrac{1}{2t_k}\|x-x_{k-1}\|_2^2$$
Note that $x_{k-1}$ and $t_k$ are *constants* in this context; the only variable is $x$. This is obviously a strongly quadratic function, so it is guaranteed to have a unique minimum. And it is differentiable, so we can determine that minimum by finding the point with zero gradient:
$$\nabla g(x) = \nabla f(x_{k-1}) + \tfrac{1}{t_k}(x-x_{k-1}) = 0$$
Isolate $x$ and you do indeed get
$$x = x_{k-1} - t_k \nabla f(x_{k-1})$$
In fact, with a bit of care, you can show that
$$g(x) = f(x_{k-1}) + \tfrac{1}{2t_k}\|x-(x_{k-1}-t_k\nabla f(x_{k-1}))\|_2^2 - \tfrac{t_k}{2}\|\nabla f(x_{k-1})\|_2^2$$
which obviously obtains its minimum at the given point, and that minimum value is $$g(x_k) = f(x_{k-1}) - \tfrac{t_k}{2}\|\nabla f(x_{k-1})\|_2^2$$

Comment: Thanks!!! Can we say something about the "projected" case $y_{k} = x_{k-1} - t_k \nabla f(x_{k-1}), x_k = \text{argmin}_{x \in \mathcal{C}} \| x - y_k\|$?  Is it equivalent to the argmin of the quadratic over the set $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: I’m pretty sure that is the case, yes.

Comment: Indeed, I think that really is the important realization. By expressing the gradient descent as a quadratic minimization then it becomes easy to see the projected or proximal gradient approaches as simple extensions of that, and derive useful results based upon that.

Comment: By the way, maybe it's worth mentioning that the second expression for $g(x)$ is derived by completing the square, which is a technique we already know from precalculus.